# iOS 5+: Read Twitter statuses/home_timeline for another user

Tags: ios, tweets

In my app I want to display tweets from another user timeline. Is it possible at all?  I can access user_timelines which doesn't require auth but for home_timelines I need to do auth but then how I can read another user public timeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to grab tweets from a specific user's home_timeline, you'll need to authenticate.  Unfortunately, your best bet is probably to just authorize and grab the account on the device.  This however, isn't a difficult task.  Below is some code I've used in a twitter application to request access to the account.

```
    // Create an account store object.
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
            // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                //At this point, the twitterAccount has been pulled into the *twitterAccount object.
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
According to the comments below, you would like to display `home_timeline` from BBC, similar to what you see in [twitter.com/BBCNews](http://twitter.com/BBCNews).  The [home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline) API call only returns the timeline of the *currently authenticated account*.  This means that you will only be able to fetch the timeline of the user that is using your application.

If you wanted to fetch the timeline of *another user*, like BBCNews, you'll need to use the [user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) API call and specify in parameters what user you want the timeline for, similar to the [twitter example that selects the timeline of the twitterapi account](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2).

Furthermore, from the sound of it, the `user_timeline` API call doesn't work for you because you also want to see the retweets.  If you take a look at [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) you'll see an optional parameter that you can use in your API call to `include_rts` which will include or exclude retweets.

This will solve your problem.  A lot of times in the past when I would work with the Twitter API and would run into problems, I would ask myself "Is the problem I'm facing a simple problem?".  If the problem you are actually facing is indeed simple, you can rest assured that the problem has likely been handled or solved already, you just haven't found the solution.  Keep cracking at it.  `user_timeline` is what you'll want to use, just play around with the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Boeckm, I know how to get user account but if I use it and access home_timelines it will return me timelines for THIS user while I want to read homeline for ANOTHER user for which of course I do not have account. The idea is to show tweets from a company timelines and display it in the app (assuming user has tweeter profile and I can use this account to access tweeter)

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline All you have to do is specify the user you want to fetch the tweets for, like so: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2 and don't forget to make sure you're authenticated.

Comment: yes, I know this but it is not home_timeline but user_timeline which is different. I need to read home_timeline as it also includes retweets

Comment: I guess I'm a bit lost here.  If you want to read the timeline for ANOTHER user, you should be using the user_timeline and passing the other user's name as a parameter in the request.  If you want to read the timeline for the CURRENT AUTHENTICATED USER, you should be using the home_timeline.  If this still doesn't solve your issue, perhaps you can use the search API and use the from:user parameter?

Comment: here is what i want in example -  In my app I want to display home_timeline from bbc: https://twitter.com/BBCNews  as you can see timeline on twitter includes not only posts from BBC but also BBC retweets i.e. currently I can see retweet for "Tim Reid ‏@TimReidBBC". This is default view when you access BBCNews page on tweeter. This is specified in https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline documentation but I do not know how to access it (home timeline for BBC)

Comment: Due to all the comments, I've updated the answer because I think I now understand the problem you're facing a bit better.